# Using OAuthAuthentication in django-tastypie to get the logged-in user from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, django, oauth, django-authentication, tastypie

Can anyone explain in detail how to use OAuthAuthentication in django-tastypie  to get the logged-in user (logged in my Django-powered site) from Javascript code? [This](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#oauthauthentication) is not clear at all. Thank you in advance!